# combinatorial lemma (is it well-known?)

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

The following should be something well?-known, but i haven't seen it anywhere,
neither have i met any references about.

Let $M^{n}$ be a $n$-dimensional oriented closed manifold with a (sufficiently
small) triangulation $\tau$. We "colour" the vertices of $\tau$ with $n+2$
colors: $v^{o}\rightarrow w(v^{o})\in$ {$1,2,...,n+2$ } and we shall say that
the correspondence $w$ is a "coloring" of $\tau$. Take an arbitrary color
$i\in$ {$1,2,...,n+2$ } and consider the $n$-simplices whose vertices are
colored with exactly the colors {$1,2,...,n+2$ }$\backslash\{i\}$. Let
$\Delta^{n}$ be such a simplex and $v_{1},...,v_{n+1}$ be its vertices ordered
according to the positive orientation of $\Delta^{n}$ induced by the
orientation of $M^{n}$. Then we write $\sigma_{i}(\Delta^{n})=1$, if the
permutation $(w(v_{1}),...,w(v_{n+1}))$ is even, and $\sigma_{i}(\Delta
^{n})=-1$ otherwise. Set $\sigma_{i}(\Delta^{n})=0$ if some vertex of
$\Delta^{n}$ is colored $i$, or there are two identically colored vertices.
Let finally

$\sigma_{i}(w)=\sum\sigma_{i}(\Delta^{n})$,

where the sum is over all $n$-simplices.

**The Claim:** The number $\sigma_{i}(w)$ does not depend on $i$:
 $\sigma_{1}(w)=\sigma_{2}(w)=...=\sigma_{n+2}(w)$. So we have a global invariant
$\sigma(w)$ of the coloring $w$.

This invariant has a **geometrical meaning**:
Consider the dual cell complex of the triangulation $\tau$, then since each
cell corresponds to a vertex $v^{o}$ of $\tau$, we may color this cell by the
color $w(v^{o})$. Let $F_{i}$ be the union of all cells colored $i$, then we
get a covering $\lambda=\{F_{1},...,F_{n+2}\}$ of $M^{n}$. It is easy to see
that the intersection of all $F_{i}$ is empty, so the canonical map of $M^{n}$
into the nerve of $\lambda$ may be considered as a map of $M^{n}$ into the
$n$-sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n}$:
$\varphi:M^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^{n}$. Then the degree of $\varphi$ equals
$\sigma(w)$:

$\deg\varphi=\sigma(w)$.

As the proofs are not sophisticated at all and the construction seems
conceptual, maybe it is worth including this material in an elementary
topology textbook. Note also that it gives a method for calculating the degree
without smooth approximation.

Of course, i don't want to repeat well-known things without citation, so any
references are welcome.

Comment: there is a much simpler way to say the geometrical meaning: consider the standard $n+1$-simplex, with vertices $1, \ldots, n+2$.  Then a coloring of the vertices of a triangulation is just the same thing as a simplicial map to this simplex.  now the statement about the degree is obvious.

Answer (score 4):

This is closely related to the Generalized Sperner's Lemma, which holds for all for simplicial manifolds with or without boundary.  See [my old survey](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/tilesurvey.pdf) for a quick introduction (Section 8.1).  Classical references include A.B. Brown and S.S. Cairns, [Strengthening of Sperner's lemma applied to homology theory](http://www.pnas.org/content/47/1/113.full.pdf+html), PNAS, 1960, and D.I.A Cohen, [On the Sperner lemma](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021980067800620), JCT (1967).  I don't immediately see how your result follows from the lemma, but recall that many extensions and generalizations are known.  I would start with these references and search forward to find your particular version.